# Add a Text Content Control to a section of the Header text

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have written a VBA script for automatically adding content controls for text between brackets (e.g. [Client Name]) that is working as intended. Unfortunately I haven't been able to create an equivalent that works for text in headers.

The following code would work if I wanted to apply a content control to the **whole** header, but I only want to use the bracketed text.

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Select
Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlText)
```

Unfortunately I can't simply input a specific range here like "Range(2,5)". If there is a way to conditionally select text within a header this could also resolve the issue, as adding the Content Control works if I manually select the text within the header.

As a note I need to keep the styles and formatting consistent. The headers use multiple styles and can require multiple content controls. As such deleting the existing text, adding the content control, and reformatting would require getting the formatting for each line somehow (this caveat I couldn't find a workaround for).

Comment: Why are you "automatically adding content controls for text between brackets"? Why didn't you create your template with the content controls already in place?

Comment: My company requires hundreds of these templates. They're part of a larger documentation propagation process we are implementing.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you aren't using templates, or at least a template containing the required portions as custom building blocks. That said, the correct way to do what you describe throughout a document would be to use a Find/Replace routine that loops through all StoryRanges (without ever using Selections), replacing each instance of the found content with the appropriate content control.

Comment: What I mean is that there isn't one single template format or structure. We're talking hundreds of actual templates (i.e. different formats, content, structures etc.), not just needing to propagate hundreds of files from one template. I can propagate a template that has content controls added already. I am creating a script to actually add these content controls to ANY template structure.

This is what I'm getting at: how do I add a content control to a section of header text? StoryRanges don't have a range function so I have been unable to add a content control to them this way.

Comment: To elaborate on my last point, I'm looking specifically for how to conditionally grab part of a StoryRange and add a content control to it